# Converting a JavaScript function to PHP and it doesn’t produce the expected output

Tags: javascript, php, function

Here is the JavaScript  function:

```
Decrypt2 = function (strIn, strKey) {
  var strOut = new String();
  lenIn = strIn.length;
  lenKey = strKey.length;
  var i = 0;
  var numA;
  var numB;
  while (i < lenIn) {
    numA = parseInt(strIn.substr(i, 2), 30);
    numB = parseInt(strIn.substr(i + 2, 2), 30);
    numKey = strKey.charCodeAt(i / 4 % lenKey);
    strOut += String.fromCharCode(numA - numB - numKey);
    i += 4;
  }
  return strOut;
};
```

And here is my attempt at converting the PHP function:

```
function Decrypt2($strIn, $strKey) {
  $strOut = '';
  $lenIn = strlen($strIn);
  $lenKey = strlen($strKey);
  $i = 0;
  $numA;
  $numB;
  while ($i < $lenIn)  {
    $numA = intval(substr($strIn,$i, 2), 30);
    $numB = intval(substr($strIn,$i + 2, 2), 30);
    $numKey = ord(substr($strKey,$i / 4 % $lenKey,1));
    $strOut .= chr($numA - $numB - $numKey);
    $i += 4;
  }
  return $strOut;
}
```

I though that this would work but it doesn’t output my expected output.

Expected input

```
<xml><flash></flash></xml>
```

Expected output

```
ćÄ
```

Unexecpted output

```
ïùÇÄ—¢
```

Comment: So people don't have to copy/paste/execute, can you provide input and outputs for both?

Comment: P.S. In JavaScript, just do `var strOut = '';`, *don't* use `new String()`.  Also, you need `var` before `lenIn` and `lenKey` (unless those are declared elsewhere).

Comment: P.P.S. In PHP, `$numA;` does nothing.  It does not declare a variable, it just does nothing.  It might even give you an error, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @RocketHazmat you don't need var before vars in javascript. `var` is used in functions to be declared locally and outside them(in window.this) as globals. If you use a variable without var it will be assigned to window.this automatically

Comment: @HellBaby: Not in strict mode :-)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar task of translating encryption/decryption functions between languages.

I would recommend that you use brackets for all mathematical statements so that differences in operator priority between php and js do not introduce differences in the output.

For example, change `$i / 4 % $lenKey` to `($i / 4) % $lenKey`

One other thing you should be aware of is that for very large numerical inputs, the php mod operator may produce NEGATIVE values, even if neither operator is negative. To work around this, you can use fmod instead.

Change `$i / 4 % $lenKey` to `fmod($i / 4, $lenKey)`

Answer (score 0):

The division in `strKey.charCodeAt(i / 4 % lenKey)`, in the javascript code, is producing a float, which the modulus doesn't cast to integer.

The php modulus on the other hand does cast it (i.e. it's equivalent to `Math.floor(i / 4) % lenKey`).

Probably makes no difference, though.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript `String.fromCharCode()` is a int to UNICODE converter. PHP `chr()` is an int to ASCII converter. You have to use a method like `mb_convert_encoding()` in php to convert integers to UNICODE.